# Configure Angular router guard

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular2-guards, angular-router-guards

Is there any way to configure a `canActivate` guard used in Angular's router?

Having this `SessionGuard`:

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionGuard implements CanActivate {

    public requireLeagues: boolean = true;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private session: SessionService, private router: Router) {
    }


    async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
        if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
            return false;
        }

        await this.session.start();

        if (this.requireLeagues && (!this.session.leagues || this.session.leagues.length == 0)) {
            //Redirect to create league page
            this.router.navigate(['/create-league']);

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And this routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SessionGuard]},// <-- requireLeagues = false
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'leagues', component: [AuthGuard, SessionGuard]},
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I would like to set `requireLeagues` to true or false depending on the route withouth having to create a new, different guard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `canActivate` method gets passed the current `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and the `RouterStateSnapshot`.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
   this.requireLeages = route.params... // something from route
}
```

Here's the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html#!#url-anchor) for ActivatedRouteSnapshot. It has a lot of useful properties, including a `data` property that you can use to store your own data to share between routes and services.